# Creating diagonal list of 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been stuck trying to think of ways to loop around the adj list so that I can make a diagonal list of 0 without affecting the numbers thats already in the array.

Here is what I have done so far...

```
def adjacency_matrix(graph_str):
    """Returns the adjacency matrix representation"""
    item = graph_str.splitlines()
    items = item[1:]
    header = item[0].split(" ")
    adj = [[] for _ in range(int(header[1]))]
    for i in items:
        v1, v2, weight = i.split(" ")
        v1 = int(v1)
        v2 = int(v2)
        adj[v1].insert(v2, weight)
        adj[v2].insert(v1, weight)
    for row in range(0, len(adj)-2):
        for col in range(0, len(adj)-1):
            if row != col and adj[row][col] is not None:
                adj[row].insert(col, "inf")
    return adj
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvOng.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (??):

```
a = []
size = 4
for i in range(size):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(size):
        a[i].append((i + 1) * (j + 1))
print(a)

# enter 0s
for i in range(size):
    a[i][i] = 0
print(a)
```